# Install Ubuntu server to run on a headless machine on RAID6-array of USB-sticks, in DHCP-less environment

Tags: installation, server, usb, headless

I happen to have a box without HDD (or CD for that matter), but with four (now clean) USB sticks, no display, on wired LAN without DHCP server (i.e. static network configuration).

I want to install latest Ubuntu Server on this box.

Is there an installation guide that would cover all of the above points? Alternatively, please point to guides that I can mash together to figure out what I need :-)

Comment: Can you add an display/keyboard for the purpose of installing?

Comment: No, or I wouldn't be asking this :-)

Comment: This seems like an astronomical corner case.  Have you tried installing on another computer referencing all your disks by UUID/label then just moving them across?

Comment: ...But I can put anything on the sticks (and have a spare one handy)

Comment: @aking1012: No, I have not. I do not have a 4-usb hub, but I can fix that. Care to point to a guide?

Comment: I don't know how fast you need to get this done, but tigerdirect has a special going -> http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=128805&SRCCODE=TIGFACEBK&cm_mmc_o=m21CjCd-2HPRRsCjC2zfGpjvCjC7vnDCNiin  coupon code GUG56350 gets it down to under $5

Comment: This isn't *that* astronomical. Ubuntu offers Kickstart which allows for fully automatic installations. You can specify the username, password, et cetera. [Ubuntu help site with more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an astronomical corner case. Have you tried installing on another computer referencing all your disks by label then just moving them across?

'No, but I can try that'

At that point it becomes a really normal install.  I'ld start [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) and tack on the caveat that you might have some issues with sound or video...but it doesn't sound like those are really relevant to your situation.

Comment: Something that I think bears noting is that I've never set up HotPlugRaid, which is what it seems like you're trying to do for an entire system(given the USB requirement).  Not sure how just yanking a USB raid member would effect the situation.

Comment: Finally managed to install the thing (based on this, actually: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID).

Comment: Hard parts: (1) find something with 4 USB ports that would not shut them down when all are in use; (2) set up boot with tftp for the thing, for Ubuntu network install /not so hard, actually/; (3) tell  BIOS on the device to boot from the correct USB stick /hardest, had to borrow a display for that/.

Comment: I have to note RAID6 is a bit on a slower side. If I'd do that again, I'll probably try to RAID5. I get a nice 32 MB/s write speed, but from time to time writing process just freezes in `D`.

Comment: Improved performance/power reliability can be had when using a large number of usb devices like that by putting them on separate controllers.  At least on my desktop, one controller is preferred over the others, so that's where you put usb media if more than one is bootable

Comment: Well, I filled all USB ports on the motherboard except one (and except front panel), so not many options here... But thanks anyway.

Comment: A part of a problem was that the RAID was re-syncing itself on each boot. This helped: `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u`.